# Agreement for de-militarization of Ukraine, good or bad?

Tags: russian-federation, ukraine, country-neutrality

Sure this won't be popular, but it's reality:

Quote:
*Russian President Vladimir Putin has expressed his preparedness to engage in discussions with his Ukrainian counterpart, with a focus on obtaining a guarantee of neutral status and the promise of no weapons on its territory.*

In consideration of many years of protracted violence, is de-militarization of Ukraine a reasonable way forward to retain Ukrainian independence?

On the on hand, it's the conditions that Putin has demanded since 2015. On the other, Putin is insipring minimal trust. Can it avert war and occupation too?

Answer (score 3):

De-Militarization of Ukraine would just make it easier for the Russian military to take over the country as they would have even less to oppose them then they currently have. At this point I don't see how Russia invading can be blamed on the Ukraine having a military especially when you consider they have a treaty with Russia regarding interfering with them.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_weapons_and_Ukraine

> On December 5, 1994 the leaders of Ukraine, Russia, Britain and the
> United States signed a memorandum to provide Ukraine with security
> assurances in connection with its accession to the NPT as a
> non-nuclear weapon state. The four parties signed the memorandum,
> containing a preamble and six paragraphs. The memorandum reads as
> follows:[10]
>
> The United States of America, the Russian Federation, and the United
> Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland,
>
> Welcoming the accession of Ukraine to the Treaty on the
> Non-Proliferation of Nuclear Weapons as non-nuclear-weapon State,
>
> Taking into account the commitment of Ukraine to eliminate all nuclear
> weapons from its territory within a specified period of time,
>
> Noting the changes in the world-wide security situation, including the
> end of the Cold War, which have brought about conditions for deep
> reductions in nuclear forces.
>
> Confirm the following:
>
> 1. The Russian Federation, the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland and the United States of America reaffirm their
>    commitment to Ukraine, in accordance with the principles of the Final
>    Act of the Conference on Security and Cooperation in Europe, to
>    respect the independence and sovereignty and the existing borders of
>    Ukraine.
> 2. The Russian Federation, the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland and the United States of America reaffirm their
>    obligation to refrain from the threat or use of force against the
>    territorial integrity or political independence of Ukraine, and that
>    none of their weapons will ever be used against Ukraine except in
>    self-defence or otherwise in accordance with the Charter of the United
>    Nations.
> 3. The Russian Federation, the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland and the United States of America reaffirm their
>    commitment to Ukraine, in accordance with the principles of the Final
>    Act of the Conference on Security and Cooperation in Europe, to
>    refrain from economic coercion designed to subordinate to their own
>    interest the exercise by Ukraine of the rights inherent in its
>    sovereignty and thus to secure advantages of any kind.
> 4. The Russian Federation, the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland and the United States of America reaffirm their
>    commitment to seek immediate United Nations Security Council action to
>    provide assistance to Ukraine, as a non-nuclear-weapon State party to
>    the Treaty on the Non-Proliferation of Nuclear Weapons, if Ukraine
>    should become a victim of an act of aggression or an object of a
>    threat of aggression in which nuclear weapons are used.
> 5. The Russian Federation, the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland and the United States of America reaffirm, in the
>    case of Ukraine, their commitment not to use nuclear weapons against
>    any non-nuclear-weapon State party to the Treaty on the
>    Non-Proliferation of Nuclear Weapons, except in the case of an attack
>    on themselves, their territories or dependent territories, their armed
>    forces, or their allies, by such a State in association or alliance
>    with a nuclear-weapon State.
> 6. Ukraine, the Russian Federation, the United Kingdom of Great Britain, Northern Ireland, and the United States of America will
>    consult in the event a situation arises that raises a question
>    concerning these commitments.
>
> — Memorandum on Security Assurances in Connection with Ukraine’s
> Accession to the Treaty on the Non-Proliferation of Nuclear
> Weapons[10]

Comment: It's a negotiation offer from the world's 2nd most powerful army surrounding the capital, is the overt military way better then? That way guarantees a hard occupation and guarantees puppet regime change, like chechnya. Presumably Ukraine can only opt for guerilla war either way. Negotiations may well keep Ukraine sovereign.

Comment: The 200 billion of annual EU oil trade that Russia stands to lose from protracted violence may secure a deal.

Comment: @LifeInTheTrees What does De-Militarization of Ukraine have to do with Russia losing out on trade deals? They are already violating treaties that they signed and they are suffering the results of the invasion with a military to stand against them, what is there to suggest this would be any different if the Ukraine didn't have a military other then they would be further along in invading them?

Comment: @LifeInTheTrees - It is also unclear why you believe that demilitarization could avoid a "puppet regime," as you say. All of Putin's rhetoric—not mealy-mouthed statements by government agents like the one you mentioned—suggest that the installation of a strong pro-Russian government in Ukraine would be the minimum acceptable outcome for him.

Comment: Well, to play the devil's advocate here, if you read Putin's full statement/speech, he's repeatedly invoked various UN articles to claim his move in Ukraine is justified to stop a "genocide".

Comment: @Fizz Not to mention deal with Nazis in the country as well as several other issues

Comment: @Joe W... Treaties with Germany led to WW1, Putin is a mafiosi, and we forget US-Lybia strategic wisdom in the influence of Ukraine. Russia's military intervention history is of much smaller geographic and demographic importance than America's. (Syria/Yemen/Iraq/Lybia/Afghanistan). Putin has been more of a capitalist and less of a belligerent than Washington. America should stop dictating policy in Europe, and replace the Russian enmity with buffers, and concentrate on CHINA. Unsatisfactorily greedy treaties on Ukraine, have given China the upper hand and we forget to divide and rule China/Rus

Comment: @LifeInTheTrees And throwing away their defense would not have prevented any of this it just would have made it easier for Russia to do what they wanted. There is zero evidence that the military forces that Ukraine had played any roll in this as evidence that Russia has been attacking non military forces as well. And if they can't honor a treaty with military forces why would they honor a treaty for a defenseless country?

Answer (score 3):

There're a few problems with your question. Let's examine:

> On the on hand, [demilitarization is] the conditions that Putin has demanded since 2015

This isn't correct. Putin demanded Minsk II be adhered to, and Minsk II [does not have a demilitarization clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minsk_agreements#Text_of_the_agreement).

> Can [demilitarization] avert war and occupation too?

It assuredly can, in the same way that Ukraine agreeing never to join NATO can assuredly avert war and occupation. "Should Ukraine agree?", however, is another question.

Here's the sequence of events since the 2015 Minsk agreements were agreed upon.

- Minsk agreements agreed.
- In Ukraine, Minsk II "[represent[s] a national humiliation and, if implemented, would require a fundamental rewriting of the country’s founding law. The 1996 constitution established Ukraine as a unitary state with a highly centralized form of government. Ukraine embarked on a significant decentralization policy in the aftermath of the 2014 Revolution of Dignity, but the Minsk accords call on Kyiv not only to recognize the independence of Donetsk and Luhansk within the country but also to give these two regions veto power over any national legislation. Such authority would mean that Russia could effectively gain control over Ukraine’s internal politics. It would also require significant constitutional amendments that no national Ukrainian politician would want to put his or her name to.](https://www.wilsoncenter.org/blog-post/minsk-mantra-can-minsk-accords-avert-war-ukraine)"
- Because Minsk II represents a national humiliation, Ukraine does not wish to implement them [unless they have no choice](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/65633/why-doesnt-the-eu-adopt-sterner-sanctions-against-people-with-connections-to-th/65637#65637). Western governments were supportive however, and backed up their support with military aid. Since nobody likes being coerced if they can help it, Ukraine largely decided not to implement the agreements in full.
- Since the agreements weren't fulfilled, the separatists refuse to return to Ukraine either. A tenuous ceasefire holds, but the conflict remained "frozen".
- The rest you know. Both sides continue to fire rockets at each other until one day (if you believe the Russian version of events) the DPR and LPR decided they can't stand it anymore and ask Russia for protection, after which Russia decides to deploy troops and "demilitarize/denazify" Ukraine.

So could Ukraine refusing Western military aid and not expanding the military have averted war and occupation? It surely would have, but it would also mean that Ukraine must do something they don't want to do at "gunpoint" (not literally, but they'd certainly feel coerced about). Would you do it if you were Ukraine?

Comment: To me, it is quite unclear whether now, with the *war literally underway*, any concession by Ukraine will necessarily change Putin's plans, and certainly nothing can avert war at this point (it is a fait accompli). Why would Putin accept a mere promise not to join NATO after so much preparation, when his rhetoric has increasingly indicated that he sees the entire Ukrainian government as illegitimate?

Comment: @Obie2.0 I suppose Ukraine could declare a unilateral ceasefire and surrender, which would stop the war, but aside from that it's probably too late.

Comment: It would stop the war, but would it change what Putin would do? It seems as if it would just make things easier for him. And if occupation is his goal—which it could be—then he would not have any reason to turn aside just because Ukraine did something nice for him.

Comment: @Obie2.0 maybe - but it would "change Putin's plans" since it stops the war.

Comment: It was treaties that caused WW1 and WW2... So why rant about a failed treaty that wasn't implemented by both sides. Is it really good for the USA to join Rus and China and fight them together? Would it have been better to accept Putin's wish to be friends with America, that he set out with Clinton? And thus divide and rule the major China Rus superpowers? Is Washington making massive strategic oversights? Why does Biden chum up with the Saudi Prince and not Putin if he is an ideologist? why not both?

Comment: @LifeInTheTrees you'd have to come to your own conclusions for those questions.